# Is it wrong to say “Today is Sam’s birthday” instead of “It’s Sam’s birthday today”?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

I was watching a YouTube video where they’re saying so. They’re also saying that it’s wrong to say ‘Today is Sunday’ instead of ‘It is Sunday today’. Are these really true?

Comment: No, you have every right to say that **Today is Sunday** or any other day, and ditto for Sam's birthday.  Whoever **they** are, they're wrong.

Comment: Please **name** the Youtube presenter and **add a link** to the source. It would be very helpful to know if the presenters were native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube videos are easy to make. You want to look at more authoritative ones.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/today_2

> Today is her tenth birthday.
>
> Today is Monday.

https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/202816 (If you didn't buy access, your local libraries may have access)

> 1607   T. Dekker Whore of Babylon sig. K2   Today is workiday with me
> for all I haue my best clothes On.
>
> 2012   N.Y. Times (National ed.) 5 Aug. (Front section) 17/3   Today
> is the end of solar summer in the Northern Hemisphere.
>
> 1917   Agric. Student (Columbus, Ohio) May 570/1   Today is an age of
> machinery and mechanical devices.

Oxford Learners Dictionaries and the quotations in Oxford English Dictionary show "Today is" is perfectly fine.

Also check https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/it_1?q=it

> ​used in the position of the subject of a verb when you are talking
> about time, the date, distance, the weather, etc.

That's why "It’s Sam’s birthday today" is also fine.

## Grammar

Grammar-wise, your Youtuber likely over-emphasize end-weight or doesn't know "today" has two parts of speech.

end-weight (see **Practical English Usage, 4ed, section 267**)

Longer and heavier structures usually come last in a clause or sentence.

Compare:

Telling us everything you know is important.

It's important to tell us everything you know.

**I merely copied limited text from my resources. You should find your ones.**